# Statistics and ML Knowledge Sources

Tags: self-study

I have a MS in Statistics but I completed my studies 10 years ago. Since then the field of Statistics/Modeling/Machine Learning has continued its rapid advance, and I feel that a number of new techniques have been developed in recent years that I was not exposed to in school. Some examples I've seen thrown around include Neural Networks and Random Forests.

I was wondering if there were good sources of knowledge on these topics - such as websites or journals, free or not, that I can subscribe to in order to stay abreast of cutting-edge topics in my field. One such website I've recently been exposed to is KDNuggets.com so I'd like to find more like that. I'm also aware of the classes on Coursera although some of them are a rather large time investment.

Please let me know if this question is too vague/broad and I can refine it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I really like the section on decision trees, tree bagging and random forests in ['Introduction to Statistical Learning'](https://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20First%20Printing.pdf) and ['Elements of Statistical Learning'](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf)